# Heroku deploy error

Tags: node.js, heroku

Hi, I have some problems: I tried to deploy a nodejs app on heroku, but when I try to open it, I get this error :

```
2017-06-08T16:08:43.221350+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=xmpp-discord.herokuapp.com request_id=6692a6c4-2563-474d-90e2-1657d83c7393 fwd="92.157.13.75" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2017-06-08T16:08:43.433802+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=xmpp-discord.herokuapp.com request_id=ab1f0f7d-4eed-4948-94e2-bb80fcd9887b fwd="92.157.13.75" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

My app is a bridge between Discord and XMPP: here It's github base: [Github](https://github.com/C0pperhead/discord-xmpp) but I ran it and setuped it, it does work in local but I want to run the program all day even if my PC isn't on.

What should or could I do?

If you need more infos tell me !

Thanks

Comment: Your app has crashed.  There is something wrong, probably it's expecting a configuration variable set that you didn't set or perhaps you didn't save all your npm modules to package.json.  It's not possible to narrow it down further with what you provided, please paste in more lines of the logs, surely there are some before those that explain the error.  Try calling `heroku logs -n 500` to get 500 log lines and paste the ones that show the error / stack trace here so we can help.

Comment: I can't, there is too many words :( How can i do ?

Comment: https://github.com/C0pperhead/discord-xmpp/blob/C0pperhead-withlogs/heroku-log

Answer (score 0):

It's right there in the logs "missing script 'start'". Either in your procfile or due to Heroku defaults your app is trying to launch using "npm start", but your package.json does not define a start script.

Either update your procfile to the correct start command or add to your package.json, in the "scripts" object something like:  "start": "node server.js" or whatever command you normally use to start the app.

Comment: Ok i'll try thanks. I usualy launch my app with 'node app.js"

Comment: I have now a packtage.json like this [https://github.com/C0pperhead/discord-xmpp/blob/C0pperhead-withlogs/package.json] but there i think there isn't ok,..